# JSTL and scriptlet code

Tags: jstl, javabeans, scriptlet

So in my JSP page I am using a javabean to get some data from MySQL.

```
<%= myObj.getContent() %>
```

Lets assume the returned data if of the following form:

```
<!-- Content Begin -->
I am trying to use JSTL from within a database field. 
<br />
<taglib:someTag id="${id}"></taglib:someTag>
<!-- Content End -->
```

But the tags don't evaluate but appears as is in the HTML Source.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

A JSP expression(<%=  %>) is used to add the result of executing a scripting expession to the response. You could have your javabean write to a file. Once you have a file you can use an include to execute it and then add to the response.
If you don't want to create a file, then  you could create a Servlet that could call your javabean. Your JSP could include the response from the Servlet.